# Deleting user - 10.38 from Hartl Book

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently attempting to follow along with [section 10.38](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec%3athe_destroy_action) from RoR Tutorial. All is going well, but the delete user link is bringing me to the user's profile page, rather than deleting the user. If I inspect the delete user link in chrome I see this:

```
<a href="/users/15" data-confirm="You sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow" title="Delete Bob Johnson">delete user</a>
```

I have also included <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %> as mentioned by Hartl in my application layout file.

I am running rails 3.1.3 and Ruby 1.9.3.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please show your rails code.
You should something like 

    `<%= link_to "delete", user, :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?",
                                    :title => "Delete #{user.name}" %> ?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hartl book has not been fully updated yet for Rails 3.1/3.2 (I think the first couple sections are available as a beta "second edition"). In Rails 3.1, you should be using `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`, not `:defaults`, otherwise the `data-method="delete"` part won't be handled properly.

Comment: Thanks Dylan. I've used :application rather than "application", which also seems to work.